# Android: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity"

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context, onmeasure

These are the problem in details :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
at io.jchat.android.view.LoginView.onMeasure_Original(LoginView.java:123);
at io.jchat.android.view.LoginView.onMeasure(LoginView.java) ;
```

And my code is:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    mContext = getContext();
    Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

    int statusBarHeight = rect.top;

    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
    int diff = (screenHeight - statusBarHeight) - height;

    if(mListener != null){
        mListener.onSoftKeyboardShown(diff);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

As a freshman, I am eager for your help. Thank you!

Comment: mContext variable is instance of BridgeContext.. You can not cast it into Activity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");

    int statusBarHeight = 0;
    if (resourceId > 0) {

         statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }

    dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
    int diff = (screenHeight - statusBarHeight) - height;
    if(mListener != null){
        mListener.onSoftKeyboardShown(diff);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you restore the problem statement..and +1 for your genuine efforts

Answer (score 0):

Class `com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext` does not extend `android.app.Activity`, which is **the** required condition to perform casting. Please check the relationship between those classes. `Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;` won't work.

Comment: Thank you. But I do need to getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame and getgetMetrics. So do you know how to make a substitue?

Comment: I'm not an android developer but will look for a way to achieve that!

Comment: There is a constructor in android.view.Window <https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#Window(android.content.Context)> where you can pass the context. so try     
`new Window(context).getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);`
. Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi,friend. I have solved the problem. Thanks for your suggestion. Window is an abstract class so it cannot be instantialed. My new code is below..

Comment: @xuange, post  your new code as the answer of this problem, do not mix up the code, as this will help others in future if they face similar problem

Comment: Sure. It is below.